# sigset_t is useful in this case?

Tags: c, sockets, signals

I'm trying to implement an easy server/client with handler for signals.

My only use for signals will be sigaction(SIG...,&sig,NULL), where:

```
sig.sa_sigaction = &closeSig;
sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;


void closeSig{
   send(ds_sock,"close",1024,0);
   close(ds_sock);
   exit(1);
}
```

If the server (or the client) receives "close", it simply closes the connection.

In this situation, is it useful to use the sigset_t, and add in it all the signals I wanto to handle, and then use sigaction like up, instead using only e sigaction?

If it's useful, can you explain me the reason? I've a beta program, and it uses a sigset on the server, but it doesn't on the client.. Thanks!

edit: I've just found out that the server also uses sigprocmask with unblock. If I don't want to use it, and I want all signals to be unblocked and that they immediatly launch their handler, I don't have to use a sigset, right? Thanks!

I'm sorry, but I can't post the code. If you can help me, that's good, if you can't, thanks anyway!

Comment: Your send() call makes no sense; it's sending 1024 bytes from a 5-byte array.  I hope that this is merely an example.

Comment: @Myria Yes it's only an example, it's 6am and I'm still studying :(
Edit: anyway I don't think it's completly wrong, I mean, I'm sending more bytes then necessary, but this shouldn't break any thing, right?

Comment: Reading off the end of an array has undefined effects.  It may be do nothing, it may cause a core dump, or it may do something else.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown for `closeSig()` is not valid C.  To be usable with `sigaction()` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, the type of the function needs to be:

```
void closeSig(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context) { … }
```

The third argument is a `void *`, but can be cast to a `ucontext_t *` (see [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)).

When you call `sigaction()`, you should ensure that the `sig.sa_mask` is set to a known value, probably by using `sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);` to clear all the bits.  This means that while a signal handler is called, other signals could still interrupt the signal handler.  If you prefer not to let that happen, use `sigfillset(&sig.sa_mask);` instead; this blocks all signals (that are blockable) while a signal handler is in effect.  Unblockable signals such as `SIGKILL` will still be delivered.

---

The comments have identified some other problems with the code fragments shown.